# How do you export a audio codec from one computer to different computer?

Tags: windows, codecs

I have a virtualized Windows Server2003 R2, it has an audio codec I would like to move off it to a newer server.  I don't have an installer for it, is their a way to manually install it on say a windows 7/8/10 box?

I was only able to find this on google...
https://hydrogenaud.io/index.php/topic,26045.0.html

That didn't work, or I missed something, any ideas?

{Edit}

I used a program called Filmerit 3.1.0 by Paul Glagle to so do something like msinfo32.exe it gave me.

```
Compression Manager Filter = ITU G.729A by VoiceAge
Filter Type = Compression Manager
Category = Audio Compressors
    Type = Default
    ID = {33D9A761-90C8-11d0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}
    CLSID = {33D9A761-90C8-11d0-BD43-00A0C911CE86}
    Merit = 00000000
Server File = c:\windows\system32\quartz.dll
    Date = 11/26/2009 5:18:04 AM
    Size = 1278464
    CLSID = {6A08CF80-0E18-11CF-A24D-0020AFD79767}
    ThreadingModel = Both
ID = 307ITU G.729A by VoiceAge
Version = 2
Merit = 00200000
Number of pins = 2
Pin = Pin 00
    bZero = False
    bRendered = False
    bMany = False
    bOutput = False
    Type = Type 00
        MajorType = {73647561-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71} - MEDIATYPE_Audio
        SubType = {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}
Pin = Pin 01
    bZero = False
    bRendered = False
    bMany = False
    bOutput = True
    Type = Type 00
        MajorType = {73647561-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71} - MEDIATYPE_Audio
        SubType = {00000133-0000-0010-8000-00AA00389B71}
Codec file = sl_g729a.acm
    FileVersion = 2.0.0.6
        Langue = English (United States)
        CompanyName = VoiceAge
        FileDescription = Audio codec for MS ACM
        InternalName = sl_g729a.acm
        LegalCopyright = Copyright. © 1999-2002.VoiceAge. All Rights Reserved.
        LegalTrademarks = 
        OriginalFilename = sl_g729a.acm
        ProductName = ITU G.729A CS-ACELP 8 kbps speech codec
        ProductVersion = 2.0.0.6
        Comments = http://www.voiceage.com
    Date = 2/4/2010 7:17:10 PM
    Size = 176128
```

I think that program it just pulling info from the windows registry.  Hopefully All I need to do find out where it's stored.

Comment: Is there a reason that you need the codec from the machine? Is it proprietary?

Comment: We get audio recordings from a business that used a Cisco CUCM, to record voip calls.  I need the codec to convert the calls to an easier to read format.  The codec in question is Sipro 133 G.729a.

Answer (score 1):

That's pretty terrible.  [Like 9 years ago, people were having trouble getting licensed copies of this codec](https://supportforums.cisco.com/discussion/10278141/uc-20-codec-sipro-lab-telecom-acelpg729-133), terrible. [Like the patents expired earlier this year](http://www.sipro.com/G729.html), terrible.  So it's pretty clearly not longer supported.  Time to transcode what you've got and tell this other company you're not going to continue to accept audio files encoded by an EoL product using an EoL codec.

Having said that, you can get a list of currently installed codecs with the [MSinfo utility](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490937.aspx), like the below, including path and filenames for your codecs.

[image]

Hopefully, it's as simple as copying the file over to your new computer (probably should be put in `%windir%\System32` witht the rest), and registering it with [regsvr](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490985.aspx), but you may have to step through a more involved installation process, or run into compatibility issues or god only knows whatever else.

Comment: Well msinfo32 didn't exist on my windows server 2003, I tried to copy it from windows 7 not compatible.  I tried that regsvr command and looks like only works with .dll not .acm files.